# Javascript - sort issue

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to sort an array that is not working correctly. No errors, just the output is displaying as: [10,5,12,15,38,45,16,1,6,5,2,25]. Please give me an idea of the issue with my  sort code.Thanks

```
var arr1 = [10, 5, 12, 15, 38, 45, 16];
var arr2 = [1, 6, 5, 2, 25];
var arr3 = merge(arr1, arr2);

function merge(arr1, arr2) {

    var combine = arr1 + "," + arr2;

    var arr3 = new Array(combine);

    for (var i = 0; i < arr3.length; i++) {

        arr3.sort(function (n1, n2) {
           return n1-n2;
        });
    }
       document.writeln("Array 3 sorted: " + arr3);

       return arr3;
  }

  merge(arr1, arr2);
```

Comment: What made you think you can glue together two arrays with a comma and it would just work? The result of that is a string. Tossing this back into an `Array` makes an array with that string as the singular element. Sorting it has no effect.

Comment: Protip: [google "javascript merge arrays"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem isn't with sorting, it's with combining the two input arrays into `arr3`.

```
var combine = arr1 + "," + arr2;
```

creates a single string that contains all the elements of `arr1` and `arr2` separated by commas. Then

```
var arr3 = new Array(combine);
```

creates an array with only 1 element, that string. You could use:

```
var arr3 = combine.split(',');
```

But it would be better to use the proper function for appending arrays in the first place:

```
var arr3 = arr1.concat(arr2);
```

See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Answer (score 1):

Concat the two together, then sort them in ascending order

```
var arr3 = (arr1.concat(arr2)).sort(function(a,b){return a-b;});
```

Answer (score 1):

you should be using `.concat()` instead of combining the two arrays with a comma. Combining the two arrays with a comma will result in a string.

solution:

`var arr3 = arr1.concat(arr2);`

then you can call `.sort()` on arr3.